# Haskel - instance of data with two arguements

Tags: haskell

How to declare Functor instance of this data type:

```
data Productish a b = Productish a b
```

I've tried this:

```
instance (Functor a, Functor b) => Productish a b where
    fmap f (Productish a b) = Productish (f a) (f b)
```

but compiler had showed error:

```
 error: ‘fmap’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘Productish’
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, your syntax is wrong. To define a `Functor` instance on `Productish`, you will need to do `instance Functor (Productish a b) where …`.

But there is also a more serious problem: The `Functor` typeclass can only be used to define a functor on one variable. So in order to define a `Functor` instance, you need to partially apply your data type. For instance, here’s the `Maybe` instance:

```hs
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing

instance Functor Maybe where   -- note that this isn’t ‘instance Functor (Maybe a)’!
    fmap f (Just a) = Just (f a)
    fmap f Nothing  = Nothing
```

Similarly, to define a `Functor` instance for your `Productish`, you need to do:

```hs
instance Functor (Productish a) where
    fmap f (Productish a b) = Productish a (f b)
```

(Note that you don’t need a `Functor` constraint on `a`, since you don’t need to map over `a`.)

So with `Functor` alone, you can only map over the second argument.

Luckily, there is also a typeclass which lets you map over both arguments. It’s called `Bifunctor`, and lives in the `Data.Bifunctor` module:

```hs
class Bifunctor p where
    bimap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d
    first :: (a -> b) -> p a c -> p b c
    second :: (b -> c) -> p a b -> p a c
```

So to make a `Bifunctor` instance for your `Productish` type, use:

```hs
instance Bifunctor Productish where
    bimap f g (Productish a b) = Productish (f a) (g b)
    first f p = bimap f id p
    second g p = bimap id g p
```

Comment: Surely `first` and `second` already have defaults which match those given here

Comment: @luqui This is true, and I did consider mentioning that. But OP looks fairly new to Haskell, and I didn’t want to complicate my answer too much. Do you think I should edit that point into my answer?